# Why can I no longer open my realm after upgrading my realm version

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swift5, ios14

[Related Issue on Realm Git](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6096)

For a very long time I've been using Realm 3.17.3 in my swift app.

Let's call that App Version 1.

A short time ago I updated my podfile to use Realm 10.7.2.

Let's call that App version 2.

After doing this and when testing on the simulator my app sometimes crashes when trying to open the default realm file.

The crash usually occurs when I am running App Version 2, checkkout App Version 1, then do a pod install and run the app.

```
 self._realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration) // crash
```

The error given by realm is:

```
NSError domain: "io.realm" - code: 2

"NSFilePath" : "../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/15EF6132-9EA7-4946-81E4-78B48B8AC5E1/data/Containers/Data/Application/2BEC8269-1CD1-4D5D-A25F-A166D0AD5E73/Documents/default.realm"  

"Underlying" : "Invalid top array (ref: 53728, size: 11) Path: ../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/15EF6132-9EA7-4946-81E4-78B48B8AC5E1/data/Containers/Data/Application/2BEC8269-1CD1-4D5D-A25F-A166D0AD5E73/Documents/default.realm"   

"NSLocalizedDescription" : "Unable to open a realm at path \'../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/15EF6132-9EA7-4946-81E4-78B48B8AC5E1/data/Containers/Data/Application/2BEC8269-1CD1-4D5D-A25F-A166D0AD5E73/Documents/default.realm\': Invalid top array (ref: 53728, size: 11) Path:."
```

My best guess is that the crash is because a newer version of realm is being replaced by an older version of realm.

I realise that this is not likely to be a  real world scenario but I'm concerned that when I do release my "App version 2" that I'm going to have a LOT of crashes.

**My specific questions are:**

1. Why is this crash happening?
2. What can I do to prevent this crash?
3. If I were to put my realm creation in a do catch, how could I recover from this error in the catch?

Comment: Why do you think that after release "App version 2" you gonna have a lot of crashes? With proper migrations it should be fine. And crash problem you have can occurs only with downgrading version

Comment: I'm just concerned / paranoid that there's something obvious Im neglecting to do. I have no schema changes. The only thing that has been changed is the version of realm.

Comment: Ah, this is fine:) But always perform migrations test before releasing new version from appstore: checkout to previous release commit, launch & use app, checkout to current release commit, ensure that version is higher than on previous, launch & check there is no crashes and "logouts".

Comment: Changing the Realm version changes *everything* about Realm, which is why you cannot open an older Realm with a newer SDK version; it has to be upgraded and it's a permanent change because it changes the entire file format. See the [Realm 10.0.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v10.0.0) release notes **Realm files opened will be automatically upgraded and cannot be read by versions older than v10.0.0**. While there is posted and accepted answer, it's not THE answer - you need to update your Realm Files and SDK's at the same time - doing anything else will be an ongoing issue.

Comment: @Jay Your comment is really the explanation to my question. If you have the time to post an answer I can accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR

In a nutshell, the issue is that Realm made significant changes to the underlying data structure from older versions to newer versions. While it does not require a migration* (the objects schema doesn't change) it does require that the SDK is updated at the same time the backing data is. This also requires Realm Studio to be updated accordingly.

MORE INFO

Here's where the issue is

> I've been using Realm 3.17.3 in my swift app.

and then

> updated my podfile to use Realm 10.7.2.

From the [Realm 10.0 Version Docs](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v10.0.0)

> NOTE: This version upgrades the Realm file format version to add
> support for new data types. Realm files opened will be automatically
> upgraded and cannot be read by versions older than v10.0.0.

What that's saying is the data that backs your existing Realm objects is totally changed. So, for example, opening your Realm file with Realm Studio (10+) will update all of your data (it does show a message) and then your existing app will no longer be able to read it and will crash with this error

> Invalid top array (ref: 53728, size: 11) Path:

Also note that if you do the inverse, where the SDK is updated and you try to open Realm with Realm Studio and get that error, you're using an older version of Realm Studio. You will need to update to Realm Studio 10.0 or higher.

Note that by updating to 10.0 or higher, that version can no longer open the legacy Realm Cloud or Realm Object Server. You need to keep version 5.x around for that.

*If you're using Realm Sync/MongoDB Realm Sync, there are significant changes from prior versions. Please review the [MongoDB Realm Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/get-started/) docs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not possible to successfully manage realm db with downgrade app version.

So, workaround is to create clear db file if your current configuration is failing like this:

```
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: currentVersion,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in })

    do {
        realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
    } catch let error {
        logger.error("Realm migration failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        // if migration failed
        let clearConfig = Realm.Configuration(
            schemaVersion: currentVersion,
            deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true
        )

        do { realm = try Realm(configuration: clearConfig) } catch {}
    }
```

Comment: While this is an accepted answer, and does 'work', it's not the cause the issue in the question. The cause is not a migration issue; it's a Realm *version* issue. With Realm 10.0.0 the entire underlying database structure was changed and is not backward compatible. So if you upgrade from 5.x to anything later, your database will be upgraded as well. The best option is to update your SDK and your Database at the same time, no migration is needed for that process as it's an underlying update, not a object property change.